# How to generate a unique list of integers within a range in Scheme. (DrRacket)

Tags: list, random, scheme, unique

I have been having some trouble trying to define a function which generates a list of length x of random integers within the range [0, y). Here is the code to generate a list of random integers:

```
(define (random-list range list-length)
  (cond
    [(zero? length) empty]
    [else (cons (random range) (random-list range (sub1 list-length)))]))
```

The trouble is that if i try to turn this code into one that generates a list of unique random integers from 0 to (range - 1)  of length (list-length) using recursion. I cannot seem to find a way to check if the random number generated is already in the list that is being created. This code runs forever:

```
(define (random-list range list-length)
  (cond
    [(zero? list-length) empty]
    [else
     (cond
       [(member? (random range) (random-list range list-length))
        (random-list range list-length)]
       [else
        (random-list range (sub1 list-length))])]))
```

Any ideas? (I'm using DrRacket, Beginning Student)

Comment: Please don't edit the code in your question based on the answers that people post.  E.g., when you changed the code based on Óscar's good suggestion, "you should check if `list-length` is zero, not `length`," you made that part of his answer not make sense anymore.  If you fix all the things that people find and edit the question, then none of the answers make any sense.  I've rolled back the edit.

Comment: Oh that's interesting, thanks I didn't realize that and will keep that in mind in the future. Just after i posted the code originally, I noticed that i didn't use very nice names for my input values and changed them, but forgot to change that the name from length to list-length in that particular line.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The first procedure has an error, you should check if `list-length` is zero, not `length`. Regarding the second procedure, the test to see if an element is already in the list is wrong, you call `random-list` when checking if the element is already present and then call it again, but you never saved the generated value. The numbers getting generated in each case will probably be different, and anyway you're not `cons`ing the result. An entirely different approach must be used.

```
; create a helper that accumulates the generated elements
(define (random-list-h acc range len)
  (cond [(zero? len) acc] ; if we're done, return accumulator
        [else
         (let ((num (random range))) ; generate and save a random number
           (cond [(member? num acc)  ; if it's already in the accumulator
                  (random-list-h acc range len)] ; then ignore it
                 [else ; otherwise add to accumulator and advance recursion
                  (random-list-h (cons num acc) range (sub1 len))]))]))

(define (random-list range list-length)
  ; call helper with initial empty accumulator
  (random-list-h '() range list-length))
```

It'll work as advertised:

```
(random-list 10 5)
=> '(5 3 7 9 6) ; just an example
```

Comment: Ah thanks, i just noticed i wasn't creating a list at all in that second function. How silly. Thanks for your suggestion, however I am not able to use it, as I am using the beginning student level (just started learning it in university) and i don't want to stray away from it until I know how to properly implement more advanced procedures.

Comment: @Plopperzz you can use most of my answer above, then. The tricky -and unavoidable- part is how are you going to save the generated random value? because you need to use the same value twice: the first time to test if it exists, and the second to actually add it. This is harder to do without a `let`